# Passport cover worn

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, airports, airport-security, biometric-passports

I’m due to fly to the Dominican Republic next month and I’m a bit concerned about my passport (UK). The gold writing on the front cover has near enough disappeared.

Has anyone else flown with a passport in a similar state? Will it be an issue or am I just overthinking? The inside of my passport is completely fine and the chip still works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are overthinking. As in real life, what really counts is what is inside and not the packaging.